# How to prompt for button press confirmation?

Tags: php, html

I'm loading data in to a html table using following function. It also creates a delete button in front of each row. I want to prompt user to either confirm or cancel. But the code does not work and it does not prompt for confirmation. Can someone show me how to do it properly?.

I use (onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')") to prompt.

```
 //This function will list categories  
 function listCategories($sqlString)
 {
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connectToDb(), $sqlString);

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
     {
         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))            
         {                
             echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$row['cat_id']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['it_category']."</td>";
                echo '<td>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="catid" value="'.$row['cat_id'].'">
                    <input class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" name="Delete" value ="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">
                </form>
                </td>'; 
             echo "</tr>";
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Aren't you getting a PHP syntax error?

Comment: <input class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" name="Delete" value ="Delete" onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { this.form.submit(); } else { return false; }"> ?

Comment: I'm getting syntax error. Im new to web application development. Thanks

Comment: onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')"is working. Is there a problem of doing it that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes around `Are you sure`. They're matching the quotes around the string argument to `echo`.

```
                echo '<td>
                <form action="" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="catid" value="'.$row['cat_id'].'">
                    <input class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit" name="Delete" value ="Delete" onclick="return confirm(\'Are you sure?\')">
                </form>
                </td>';
```